# VirtualBox: how to extend view in the graphic mode?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have CentOS-5.6 running on the Oracle's VirtualBox. I would like to know if it possible to have it in full-screen size when running X Window applications. I know such feature is available with VMWare player (you need to download additional vmware tools).

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate please? VirtualBox has a fullscreen mode just like VMWare player so I'm not sure if that is what you are looking for or something beyond that. Also VirtualBox has guest additions (similar to vmware tools) that have to be installed after the guest OS.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough: when I maximize the VirtualBox window, it still has the working area small, may be quarter of the screen size, but I want to have it really maximized. If this can be supported by guest additions, which one I need to download? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Guest Additions already come with VirtualBox by default. Try <Host_key+D> in your guest system (or "Devices"->"Install Guest Additions" in the menu). This should mount the CD image with the Additions. You should be able to install them from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the instructions on [VirtualBox's site](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idp11850096) for installing Guest Additions. That should allow the screen to automatically resize when you fullscreen VirtualBox. In addition, you may have to adjust the screen resolution in X afterwards if Guest Additions alone don't solve your problem.

Comment: After you have Guest Additions installed, you can use <Host_key>+F to switch to and from fullscreen mode.

Comment: Thank you very much for advices. GuestAdditions were indeed included in VBox distribution, I followed the instructions and installed them.

Comment: Glad to help. If that solved your problem, please select the answer as the correct one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need Virtual Box guest extensions.

In order to install them you first need the RPMForge repository added for yum, follow these instructions:

> http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge#head-5aabf02717d5b6b12d47edbc5811404998926a1b

Then run this command in a terminal:

```
yum install dkms
```